# Who produce class file for jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

Is it the jdk compiler?
Or the Tomcat(or other web server e.g. WebLogic)?
If Tomcat produces the class files,does the class files pass by any compiling-check,like java compling check?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The servlet container(like tomcat) compile the jsp to java file ,and then compile the java file to class file through `JDTCompiler` or `AntCompiler`,the following code is implementation of create target compiler in Tomcat:

```
public Compiler createCompiler() throws JasperException {
    if(this.jspCompiler != null) {
        return this.jspCompiler;
    } else {
        this.jspCompiler = null;
        if(this.options.getCompiler() == null) {
            this.jspCompiler = this.createCompiler("org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler");
            if(this.jspCompiler == null) {
                this.jspCompiler = this.createCompiler("org.apache.jasper.compiler.AntCompiler");
            }
        } else {
            this.jspCompiler = this.createCompiler("org.apache.jasper.compiler.AntCompiler");
            if(this.jspCompiler == null) {
                this.jspCompiler = this.createCompiler("org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler");
            }
        }

        if(this.jspCompiler == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(Localizer.getMessage("jsp.error.compiler"));
        } else {
            this.jspCompiler.init(this, this.jsw);
            return this.jspCompiler;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat is calling internal java compiler,

See [Tomcat 7 documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jasper-howto.html):

> compiler - Which compiler Ant should use to compile JSP pages. The
> valid values for this are the same as for the compiler attribute of
> Ant's javac task. If the value is not set, then the default Eclipse
> JDT Java compiler will be used instead of using Ant.
>
> compilerSourceVM - What JDK version are the source files compatible with(Default value: 1.6)
>
> compilerTargetVM -> What JDK version are the generated files compatible with? (Default  value: 1.6)

see also [pre compile JSP using Tomcat](http://javapapers.com/jsp/how-to-pre-compile-jsp/)

> Apache Tomcat 6.0 uses Eclipse JDT Java compiler to perform JSP java
> source code compilation.

See also [using WebLogic compiler in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005397/using-the-weblogic-jsp-compiler-in-tomcat)

> JSP compilers are very much like regular Java compilers, with the main
> exception being that they take JSP files as "source code" instead of
> .java files.

Comment: Add tomact 7 documentation

Answer (score 0):

The subject of JSP compilation is the responsibility of the Application Server (in that sense, you can say that "Tomcat" or "Weblogic" compiles the JSP).

For example, [Tomcat does this with the Jasper Engine](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jasper-howto.html), JBoss does the same, [Weblogic also compile the JSPs automatically](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/jsp/reference.html#65756)

> ... the JSP Servlet automatically calls the WebLogic JSP compiler to process your JSP pages ...

The basic principle being that

- You can compile JSPs at runtime : (in Tomcat and JBoss, but I guess in many servers) there is an internal, server wide, ServletFilter intercepting *.jsp *.jpsx, that handles the request to the server's internal compilation engine if need be.
- You can compile at packaging time, with various tools (tomcat provides a Ant task, Weblogic has a specific module for that, sometimes even maven plugins are created, ...)

How (by which tool) the actual bytecode generation is done, is unspecified as far as I remember. 
Tomcat uses Eclipse JDT but allows the use of other compilers with a specific option, weblogic uses javac by default [and also allows an override](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/jsp/reference.html).

See also : [How does jsp work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607415/how-does-jsp-work)